# use tornado coroutine in call stack

Tags: python, tornado

I am new to tornado and have some questions about tornado's coroutine.
if i have a call stack looks like:

```
func_a => func_b => func_c => func_d
```

and func_d is an asynchronous function and I use yield and @gen.coroutine decorator.
just like this:

```
@gen.coroutine
def redis_data(self, id):
    ret = yield asyn_function()
    raise gen.Return(ret)
```

Must I use `yield` and `@gen.coroutine` with `func_c`, `func_b` and `func_a`?

Comment: Does that mean func a,b,c are syncornous functions?

Comment: synchronous andis there some difference if the func a, b, c are synchronous or not?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, all your coroutine's callers must also be coroutines, and they must yield the result of your coroutine.

Why? No coroutine can do I/O without executing a yield statement. Look at your code: might it need to talk to the server? Then it must yield. So must its caller, and so on up the chain, so that ultimately you have yielded to the event loop. Otherwise the loop cannot make progress and the I/O does not complete.

This is both a technical requirement of coroutine code, and an advantage of coroutines over threads. You always know by looking at your code when you can be interrupted:

https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2014/02/unyielding.html

For more on refactoring coroutines, see:

http://emptysqua.re/blog/refactoring-tornado-coroutines/

Comment: @tyouicn is there anything more I can help you with, or will you accept my answer as "correct" on Stack Overflow?

Comment: This does not still hold true, because there is the `await` keyword, right? I think one can now replace yield with await for this purpose, but I find the documentation to be quite confusing in that regard, so I am not sure.

Comment: It's still true that all coroutine callers must be coroutines. You can define your coroutines with "async def" and use "await", or define them with "gen.coroutine" and "yield" in Python 3.4 and older. See http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/latest/guide/coroutines.html